# Creating azure ml experiments merely using python notebook within azure ml studio

Tags: python, azure, jupyter-notebook, azure-machine-learning-service

I wonder if it is possible to design ML experiments without using the drag&drop functionality (which is very nice btw)? I want to use Python code in the notebook (within Azure ML studio) to access the algorithms (e.g., matchbox recommender, regression models, etc) in the studio and design experiments? Is this possible?

I appreciate any information and suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithms used as modules in Azure ML Studio are not currently able to be used directly as code for Python programming.

That being said: you can attempt to publish the outputs of the out-of-the-box algorithms as web services, which can be consumed by Python code in the Azure ML Studio notebooks. You can also create your own algorithms and use them as custom Python or R modules.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So, for now, I will always need to use the visual interface to design the experiments. I just wanted to make sure!